What's the difference between Pint's "Quantity" and "PlainQuantity"?
My IDE (type-checking provided by the Pyright language server) doesn't like me passing pint.Quantity instances to functions type-hinted with pint.Quantity:
from pint import Quantity

def get_units(quantity: Quantity):
   return quantity.units

get_unit(Quantity(value=1, units="m"))  # IDE complains here

My language server says this:
Argument of type "PlainQuantity[Any]" cannot be assigned
to parameter "quantity" of type "Quantity" in function
"get_unit" [E]

My questions are: what is PlainQuantity? Why does Quantity not return an instance of Quantity? Am I doing something wrong?

Pint has a facet systems that converts generic to special classes. You have to take this into account when using type checking.

Looking at the source code, it seems that they import PlainQuantity as Quantity, which I believe is why your IDE expects PlainQuantity here.
from .facets.plain import PlainQuantity as Quantity

In the documentation, they seem to rather use pint.UnitRegistry.Quantity to refer to Quantity.
import pint

class MyQuantity(pint.UnitRegistry.Quantity):
    ...

